How can I add the same javascript effect to different elements in my html?
I am quite new to coding, and I started doing it for a neocities website, in which I added a rainbow glow text effect, but now I want other elements to have the same effect and whenever I try copying it, it just applies it to the first one. Is there any way in which I can have the same effect for multiple elements?
<span id="rainbow"> Choco Chip Neocities </span>

I tried changing the ID for my other text to "rainbow2" and doing the same by duplicating the effect down below, changing the ID inside it too, but it won't work.
<!-- Rainbow Text -->
<script> function addLoadEvent(e) {
  var t = window.onload;
  if (typeof t != "function") window.onload = e;
  else window.onload = function() {
    if (t) t();
    e()
  }
}

function regenbogen() {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var e, t;
    rainbow = document.getElementById("rainbow");
    raintxt = rainbow.firstChild.nodeValue;
    while (rainbow.childNodes.length) rainbow.removeChild(rainbow.childNodes[0]);
    for (e = 0; e < raintxt.length; e++) {
      t = document.createElement("span");
      t.setAttribute("id", "rain" + e);
      t.appendChild(document.createTextNode(raintxt.charAt(e)));
      if (alink) {
        t.style.cursor = "pointer";
        t.onclick = function() {
          top.location.href = alink
        }
      }
      rainbow.appendChild(t)
    }
    rainbow = setInterval("raining()", speed)
  }
}

function raining() {
  var e, t;
  for (e = 0; e < raintxt.length; e++) {
    t = raincol[(e + raincnt) % raincol.length];
    document.getElementById("rain" + e).style.color = t;
    if (glow) document.getElementById("rain" + e).style.textShadow = t + " 0px 1px " + glow + "px"
  }
  raincnt++
}
var speed = 100;
var glow = 5;
var raincol = new Array("#ff0000", "#ff5500", "#ffaa00", "#ffff00", "#aaff00", "#55ff00", "#00ff00", "#00ff55", "#00ffaa", "#00ffff", "#00aaff", "#0055ff", "#0000ff", "#5500ff", "#aa00ff", "#ff00ff", "#ff00aa", "#ff0055");
var alink = "";
var rainbow, raintxt, raincnt = 0;

addLoadEvent(regenbogen) 
Update: I changed the ID within the span to Class, and exchanged the "document.getElementById" to "document.getElementsByClassName" inside the java code, and the effect didn't work anymore.

regenbogen() is only referring to the original element with id="rainbow"; it doesn't touch your duplicated element. I would use class="rainbow" for all elements, rather than an id, then update regenbogen() to get the elements by classes and iterate over those.

@mykaf I just did that, changed all the "getElementsbyId" stuff to class name and it didn't work!!

What exactly didn't work? Are there any errors in your console? It's not as simple as just changing that method; you'll have to iterate over the results and adjust accordingly.

I changed the "span id=" to "span class=" with the same rainbow name, and then replaced all "document.getElementById" to "document.getElementsByClassName"

Then update your question to also show your attempted solution, and explain why/how that failed (in the question, not the comments; comments are ephemeral by design).

Please read and understand https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return
